# Grouping and Then Sorting in a DataFrame (Index Problem - Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has four columns of data. The first is the frame number of a video, the second and third are x and y positions of particles in the image, and the fourth frame is the number that has been assigned to the particle to keep track of them separately (example below):

```
from pandas import DataFrame

Data = {'frame':  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        'x': ['First value', 'Second value',...],
        'y':  ['First value', 'Second value',...],
        'particle':  [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
        }

df = DataFrame(Data, columns = ['frame', 'x', 'y', 'particle'])
```

My dataframe also contains an index which has the same values as the frame column.

My goal is to first group by particle, then sort by frame number within the particle groups. There are many examples of this online, but the index seems to be causing some issues. I have tried this:

```
grouped_tracks1 = tracks1.sort_values('frame').groupby('particle').reset_index()
```

but that returns the following error:

> 'frame' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

I have also tried sorting by index,

```
grouped_tracks1 = tracks1.sort_index().groupby('particle').reset_index()
```

however, this also gives an error and I would prefer just to sort by frame and completely ignore the index. At the end of the sorting and grouping, I would like to have a dataframe that is grouped by particle and sorted within those groups.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `groupby()` requires an aggregation function (`min`, `max`, `mean`, `sum`, `count`, etc.). You mention: *my goal is to first group by particle, then sort by frame number within the particle groups*. Your attempt actually sorts first then groups by. You can sort by both columns, split data frame by *particle* subset data frames, or run aggregation.

Comment: Hey @Parfait, thanks for the reply! So I tried your suggestions, but doing two sort_values still gives me the error about the indexing and also doesn't seem to give the order I am looking for. I also have been looking around at aggregation, but I am not entirely sure how I would apply that. Do you have an example of your suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...I receive no error when using aggregation. Run this [pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/2c19a2ca-8794-47c1-89f6-f2376eae577d/). Otherwise please set up a runnable, [mcve] that reproduces your error.

Comment: Using the code that you provided on pyfiddle, I get the same error as before that "'frame' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous." I think that is because my index holds the exact same values as my frame. I have tried resetting the index, but that doesn't seem to help unfortunately.

Comment: It runs fantastically on pyfiddle, but I think there is a problem with my actual dataframe specifically that is causing the problem.

Comment: Hey @Parfait ! Just wanted to say thanks so much for your help, I was able to reset the index and then use your methods effectively :) Great pyfiddle!